# vsftpd config work in one server but not in other

Tags: amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I am seting up an ec2 instance.

It has a very similar configuration with another instance I have seted up, but for some reason I can make vsftpd work in the new one.

This is my config file:

```
passwd_chroot_enable=yes

listen=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

nopriv_user=vsftpd

virtual_use_local_privs=YES

guest_enable=YES

user_sub_token=$USER

local_root=/root/to/$USER

chroot_local_user=YES

allow_writeable_chroot=YES

hide_ids=YES

guest_username=vsftpd

pasv_max_port=41000

pasv_min_port=40000

port_enable=YES

pasv_enable=YES

pasv_address=XX.XX.XX.XX
```

The only thing that changes is pasv_address.

Any clue what can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your security groups match?

Comment: yes, they are identical

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it is working now. It seem like some sintax error or something like that.

I deleted and write again the config file and all solved.